# socket.io server does not terminate tcp connection when client disconnects due to a network error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am running a nodejs server and using socket.io 1.3.5 for handling websocket connections. When server receive a socket disconnect event with "ping timeout" or "transport close", it disconnects the socket but do not clear all the binding. It prints the below log

```
socket.io:client client close with reason ping timeout
socket.io:socket closing socket - reason ping timeout
socket.io:client ignoring remove for WX-M8GL6SvkQtxXMAAAA
```

The strange thing I have noticed when socket disconnects due to some network error, the tcp socket binding from server to browser is not cleared and remains in ESTABLISHED state forever. I can see the the below mentioned connection even after 12 hrs of receiving disconnect due to ping timeout.

```
node      29881 user   14u  IPv4 38563924      0t0  TCP 10.5.7.33:5100->10.5.6.50:49649 (ESTABLISHED)
node      29881 user   15u  IPv4 38563929      0t0  TCP 10.5.7.33:5100->10.5.6.50:49653 (ESTABLISHED)
node      29881 user   16u  IPv4 38563937      0t0  TCP 10.5.7.33:5100->10.5.6.60:49659 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What can I do to remove the stale connections on socket disconnect events ?

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm having. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! According to this issue, there is a bug in SocketIO which is fixed in version 1.4.x:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2118

I have upgraded to v1.4.5 and the TCP connections are now correctly closed after the SocketIO connection closes.